# How to give path to a tab which is not active in other page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, tabs

I have a header page that is accessed by another page. On the header page, I have a bell icon, on clicking the bell icon, it should go to a tab on another page. How to achieve this.

Header page code:

```
<div class="notify  id="notify">
    <a href="/myAccount#message" class="not-bell"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></a>
</div>
```

My account page contains certain tabs

```
   <div class="nav-tabs-custom profile_tab" id="tabs">
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" class="active show">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pass" data-toggle="tab">Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="/list" data-toggle="tab">My Listings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#message" data-toggle="tab" id="msg" >Message</a></li>
         </ul>


<div class="tab-content">
     <div class="active tab-pane" id="profile">
        ---
     </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="pass">
        ---
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="message">
        ---
     </div>

</div>
```

On clicking the bell icon , path should be message tab of my account page. But the path shows the profile tab.

What my output shows on clicking the bell icon is

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULlho.png)

How to move to message tab, when click on bell icon .

Comment: It's simple delete active to the first tab then create a js for select `#value` of link then put active tag base to the `#value` link. Remember if value is empty put into the first `<li>`

Comment: @Simone Rossaini . Can you help with the code?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from my code below i add `data-contentabs` and `data-ultabs` then i use `window.location.hash` (into this example i used simple variable because we are in iframe) and use this value for check if exist a div with that value and add active class into that.

```js
const hash = 'message'; // In your live version ---> window.location.hash;
if (hash) {
  let div = document.querySelector('[href*="' + hash + '"]');
  let div2 = document.querySelector('#' + hash);
  if (div === null || div2 === null) {
    FirstHash();
  } else {
    div.classList.add('active');
    div2.classList.add('show');
    div2.classList.add('active');
  }
} else {
  FirstHash();
}

function FirstHash() {
  let div = document.querySelector('ul[data-ultabs] > li:first-child > a');
  let div2 = document.querySelector('div[data-contentabs] > div:first-child');
  if (div) {
    div.classList.add('active');
  }
  if (div2) {
    div2.classList.add('show');
    div2.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="nav-tabs-custom profile_tab" id="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-ultabs>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab" class="active show">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pass" data-toggle="tab">Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="/list" data-toggle="tab">My Listings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#message" data-toggle="tab" id="msg">Message</a></li>
  </ul>


  <div class="tab-content" data-contentabs>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
      <p>SECTION PROFILE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="pass">
      <p>SECTION PASS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="message">
      <p>SECTION MESSAGE</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you edit the value of hash with empty or wrong value, you will see the script will active the first tab.

Ps. Clearly this is a basic code, i suggest you to edit and change name of variable and put all into a function

Comment: On executing this code, two content shows, profile contents and message contents are displaying together.I want to display only message tab contents

Comment: As you can see from my example only one is displayed, you wrong for sure into html you have set `active/show`, look you first code you hardcoded `active` into `<li>` of `nav-tabs` and `active` in `tab-content`.

Comment: Can you make it clear

Comment: Profile tab is still active

Comment: If you copy my code it works as you can see in my snippet :), I just said you must have got the html class wrong.